# Query Interface for Lucky Framework

Tags: crystal-lang, lucky-framework

How can I test/write queries in a terminal (**Query Interface**) for Lucky Framework 

(similar to `rails console` in RoR)

Comment: Since crystal doesn't have a repl like `irb` at present, I guess there is no such thing in `Lucky`.

Comment: Not clear but maybe they expect you to do browser tests? https://luckyframework.org/guides/browser-tests/

Answer (score 2):

The `lucky exec` command will open a text editor in which you can type commands like in rails c.
It will compile your instructions and output the result.

Comment: ps the interactive console for crystal is icr 
https://github.com/crystal-community/icr